# Redirect and Use Explode Instead of Get to get Variable Value into Model

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect based on item in url which can take multiple parameters.

my target url is

```
http://mywebsite/2623-Sq-Ft-Office-for-Rent-In-Pinnacle-Business-Park-Prahlad-Nagar-Ahmedabad-For-Rs-1.44-Lakh-Per-Month-prid-5102
```

my source url is

```
 http://mywebsite/views/propertyview.php?property_id=5102
```

prid-5102 and property_id=5102 refer to the same and can take different values like 5103, 5104 or 5105 and so on.  Basically i want to ignore everything before prid and point to the target url and pass the numerical value after prid to the target url.

**The Following seems to work but I want to get opinion if this is the right way to do it**

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)prid-([0-9]+)$ views/propertyview.php?property_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

**php model (using explode instead of get)**

```
$c = explode('prid-',$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]);
$result = explode('/', end($c));
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: I don't believe that this RewriteRule ^(.*)prid-([0-9]+)$ views/propertyview.php?property_id=$1 [NC,L]  can work. Ether you have to use $2 instead of $1 or you have to change the matching criteria  to ^.*prid-([0-9]+)$

Comment: Please don't change your question topic every view minutes? First you want so solve this with .htacces and mod-rewitre ... now you looking for a PHP solution... what do you really want?

Comment: @Webdesigner its working you can believe whatever you like

Comment: So you say $_GET['property_id'] has a value of eg. '5102'?  If so what is your problem? That was your original question!!!

Comment: Read the question carefully before ranting.

Comment: You changed the question... my answer if for a prior version of this question ...see the edit command.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much

Comment: @Pichai You arguably changed the question's meaning. This is not the goal of the edit function. If the question was not clear to begin with, you should have waited until it was before posting. In any event, the question as you edited it, "Is it a good way to do stuff", is off-topic and will be closed as primarily opinion based, so you'd be better off with the previous version.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier  the question was up for 1 if not 2 days, and was not getting any answers... that was the reason for changing the title... SO only suggests to change the topic and content if not getting answers or getting downvotes.  People tend to take things personally.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite based on your requested URI not a Query String (this is what comes after the ?).

Then I would refine you matching criteria a little bit. `prid-([0-9]+)` would mean the word "prid-" should be followed by one or unlimited digit **anywhere** in your URI. This should only work if the number is at the end I would explicitly include this ($ means end of string) in your matching criteria (^.* is optional in your case, but implicitly it is there).

If the number should only have a min. and max. length I would put this also in the matching criteria {min,max} (e.g. min=1 and max=4 would be {1,4}). If the number should have exact 4 digit just do `{4}`. If it should be relay 1 or unlimited than the + is fine.

`\d` and `[0-9]` does mean the same.

I'm not sure if your really need the [NC] Flag, because if "prid-" is always lower case you can remove it, if not keep it.

Add the [QSA] Flag that other Query String that may be also included in your original URL will also passed to the rewrite path e.g. `/real-long-uri-string-with-prid-1234?parameter=value`.
In this case you get `/views/propertyview.php?property_id=1234&parameter=value`

Because we want to use the matching criteria from the RewriteCond we have to use the % and not the $ symbol. So the whole thing would look like this now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*prid-(\d{1,4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /views/propertyview.php?property_id=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Because the URI can also be selected in the RewriteRule itself, **we can** do it in one line (now we have to use the $):

```
RewriteRule ^.*prid-(\d{1,4})$ /views/propertyview.php?property_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

**EDIT:**
This answer refers to a prior version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46481496/4 Now to topic has changed completely.